# 'New' method not found in Rails app, but it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question. I am learning Rails from scratch, so thanks for bearing with me.

So, I have a 'Person' model, shown below

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    has_and_belongs_to_many :events, through: :event_people
    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
    validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

and have created a form to create a new person, with associated team ID

```
<h1>Add new person</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <%= form_with url: new_person_path  do |person| %>
       <div class="form-group">
        <%= person.label :first_name %>
        <%= person.text_field :name, id: :person_first_name, class:"form-control" %>
   </div> 

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= person.label :last_name %>
    <%= person.text_field :name, id: :person_last_name, class:"form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <%= person.label :email %>
    <%= person.text_field :email, id: :person_email, class:"form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <%= person.label :job_title %>
    <%= person.text_field :job_title, id: :person_job_title, class:"form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <% @teams = Team.all %>
    <%= person.label :team %>
    <%= person.select(:team_id, @teams.collect{|a| [a.name, a.id]},  { include_blank: true }, {:class => "form-control"}) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= person.submit 'Submit button', {:class => 'btn btn-primary'}%>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

and my routes.rb file is set up like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :people
    resources :teams
    resources :organisations
    resources :events
end
```

But whenever I submit the form to create a new person, I get the following error in the console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/people/new 404 (Not Found)
```

Event though the relevant methods exist in my people_controller.rb:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
def index
    @people = Person.all
end
def show
    @people = Person.find(params[:id])
end
def new
    @people = Person.new
     respond_to do |format|
        format.html  # new.html.erb
        format.json  { render :json => @people }
      end
end

def create
   @people = Person.new(params[:person])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @people.save
      format.html  { redirect_to(@people,
                    :notice => 'Person was successfully created.') }
      format.json  { render :json => @people,
                    :status => :created, :location => @people }
    else
      format.html  { render :action => "new" }
      format.json  { render :json => @people.errors,
                    :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an underlying model you will want to use `<%= form_with model: @people do |person| %>`

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Answer (score 0):

You are posting to a method which, at least as far as I can tell, is supposed to output an empty form for entering attributes of your person.

Try a GET first, which would be in keeping with the rails interpretation of is REST URLs. Likely, the correct route also has no `/new` at the end.

Next, try `rails routes` to list all available routes.

By the way, if in development, rails should give you a meaningful, large help page, likely including available routes. Check your `development.rb` for some flag to enable that.